# Entity Framework auto populating wrong entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I'm developing the Music Store sample app with ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework and WCF.

This is a layered application which has a common layer for the entities.

I have written a seed method which works fine, but when I try to add an `Album` to the `Cart`, another duplicate `Album` is also adding to the `Album` table plus duplicate `Artists` are also added. This happens when I add Album = album statement when populating the `Cart` object. I added this statement since when I create my view it generates null for `item.Album.Title` entry

This is my code:

```
public static void AddToCart(Album album, string ShoppingCartID)
{
            using (MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities())
            {
                // Get the matching cart and album instances
                var cartItem = db.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
                    c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartID
                         && c.AlbumId == album.AlbumId);

                if (cartItem == null)
                {
                    // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
                    cartItem = new Cart
                    {
                        AlbumId = album.AlbumId,
                        CartId = ShoppingCartID,
                        Count = 1,
                        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                        Album = album
                    };

                    db.Carts.Add(cartItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the item does exist in the cart, then add one to the quantity
                    cartItem.Count++;
                }

                // Save changes
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

Model classes:

```
namespace MusicStore.Core
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    //[Bind(Exclude = "AlbumId")]
    public class Album
    {
        [DataMember]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [DisplayName("Genre")]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [DisplayName("Artist")]
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
        [Range(0.01, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 100.00")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [DisplayName("Album Art URL")]
        [StringLength(1024)]
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MusicStore.Core
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class Cart
    {
        [Key]
        [DataMember]
        public int RecordId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CartId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Count { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Seed method:

```
namespace MusicStore.Data
{
    internal class CommonDBInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MusicStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
        {
            var genres1 = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Rock",
                    Description = "Rock",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Jazz",
                    Description = "Jazz",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Metal",
                    Description = "Metal",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Alternative",
                    Description = "Alternative",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Disco",
                    Description = "Disco",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Blues",
                    Description = "Blues",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Latin",
                    Description = "Latin",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Reggae",
                    Description = "Reggae",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Pop",
                    Description = "Pop",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Classical",
                    Description = "Classical",
                    Albums = new List<Album>()
                },
            };
            genres1.ForEach(d => context.Genres.Add(d));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var artist1 = new List<Artist>
            {
                new Artist
                {
                    Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra",

                },
                 new Artist
                {
                    Name = "Barry Wordsworth & BBC Concert Orchestra",

                },

            };

            artist1.ForEach(d => context.Artists.Add(d));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var album1 = new List<Album>
            {
                new Album { Title = "The Best Of Men At Work",  Price = 8.99M,  AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif",Genre = genres1.FirstOrDefault(d => d.GenreId == 1), Artist  = artist1.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ArtistId == 1) },
               new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I",  Price = 8.99M, AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif",Genre = genres1.FirstOrDefault(d => d.GenreId == 2),Artist  = artist1.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ArtistId == 2) },

            };

            album1.ForEach(s => context.Albums.Add(s));

            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
namespace MusicStore.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
        MusicShoppingCartMgr.Cart serviceref1 = new MusicShoppingCartMgr.Cart();
        MusicShoppingCartMgr.iShoppingCart servicemethodref1 = new iShoppingCartClient();
        //
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Set up our ViewModel
            var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
            {
                CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(cart.ShoppingCartId),
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(cart.ShoppingCartId)
            };

            // Return the view
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/AddToCart/5

        public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
        {
            var addedAlbum = servicemethodref1.GetAlbum(id);

            // Add it to the shopping cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            cart.AddToCart(addedAlbum, cart.ShoppingCartId);

            // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MusicStore.Web.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h3>
    <em>Review</em> your cart:
</h3>
<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
</p>
<div id="update-message">
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Album Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Price (each)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Album.Title, "Details", "Store", new { id = item.AlbumId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Album.Price
            </td>
            <td id="item-count-@item.RecordId">
                @item.Count
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.RecordId">Remove from cart</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="cart-total">
            @Model.CartTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Question is**: why it is getting auto populate as such unusual way, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the duplication because into your `AddToCart` method, you instantiated a new context `MusicStoreEntities`. That context doesn't know anything about the `Album` entity you pass through `album` parameter.

So when you did this code:

```
cartItem = new Cart
{
    // [...]
    Album = album
};
```

and called `db.Carts.Add(cartItem);`, the `cartItem` will be on `Added` state. EF will also check the `cartItem` object graph and found that `album` was not tracked by the new context (remember this instance came from your method's parameter) and then by default it will also put that entity on `Added` state. EF will do the same with `album` object graph and you will get the artist of that album on `Added` state too. When calling `db.SaveChanges();`, each entity with `Added` state will be considered as a generate a new insertion into the database so that is why you've duplication.

To fix the problem, you can call `db.Attach(album)` and let the context take care about the entity like below:

```
using (MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities())
{
     db.Albums.Attach(album);

    // [...]
}
```

Or intead of using the `album` instance, you can just set the foreign key property `AlbumId` and get rid of `Album` property assignation. So you'll just have this when creating a new cart item:

```
cartItem = new Cart
{
    AlbumId = album.AlbumId,
    CartId = ShoppingCartID,
    Count = 1,
    DateCreated = DateTime.Now
};
```

Comment: auto populating issue is corrected , but the null issue is still there I must post separate Question for that